# how to stop setInterval in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, setinterval

i am running a `setinterval` function to check for a payment from coinbase in my react native app, i run the function after every 10 seconds, after the payment has been made, i clear the `setinterval` and navigate to the homepage, but still the `setinteval` keeps running how can i stop this?

```
      useEffect(() => {
        getData();
        myinterval();
      }, []);
    
      const myinterval= () => setInterval(function () {
        checkCharge();
      }, 10000);

      const stopCounter = () => {
        clearInterval(myinterval);
      }

  const checkCharge = async () => {
    try {
      ...SOME_CODE_HERE...
      stopCounter()        
      navigation.navigate("HomeScreen");
          
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i ran into a similar problem some months back, this soluion should work perfectly:

```
const myinterval = setInterval(function () {
      checkCharge();
 }, 10000);
```

but in my case, since I store the `setInterval` in a variable instead of a function, I had some weird problems, like the `setInterval` might run three times or keep on running even after I used `clearInterval(INTERVAL_NAME);` so if you want to check if a payment has been made, create a button that would tell the user to click when they have made the payment, this would be a lot safer than to run the function inside of `setInterval`

Answer (score 2):

I believe it's because `myinterval` is assigned to a function and not the actual return value of the `setInterval()` function. So try to change

```js
const myinterval = () => setInterval(function () {
        checkCharge();
      }, 10000);
```

to

```js
const myinterval = setInterval(function () {
        checkCharge();
      }, 10000);
```

and then canceling the `myinterval` variable with `clearInterval(myinterval);`

Answer (score 0):

You aren't using the return from `myinterval()` to clear the `setInterval`. `setInterval()` returns an id that is used to clear the interval. When you call the function `myinterval`, it is returning that ID. What you need to do is store that ID in a variable that you can use to clear the interval.

```js
...
function createInterval(){
    return setInterval(checkCharge, 10000);
}

function stopCounter(id){
    clearInterval(id);
}
...
var id = createInterval();
...

function checkCharge(){
    try {
        ...
        stopCounter(id);
        ...
    } catch(e){
        console.error(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hold `myinterval` in a state

```
import { useState } from 'react'

const [refreshId, setRefreshId] = useState() 

const myInterval = setInterval(function () { checkCharge() }, 10000)

setRefreshId(myInterval)

const stopCounter = () => { clearInterval(refreshId) }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone is using Animated component and intervals, I had to clear the interval in the callback function in the start method, clearing the interval after or before was not clearing at all.

```
Animated.timing(
        dynamicCircle,
        {
          toValue: 0,
          useNativeDriver: true,
          duration: 1,
        }
      ).start(() => {
        clearInterval(circleAnimationInterval);
      });
```